# AWK process data until next match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, sh

I am trying to process a file using awk. 
sample data:

```
   233;20180514;1;00;456..;m
   233;1111;2;5647;6754;..;n
   233;1111;2;5647;2342;..;n
   233;1111;2;5647;p234;..;n
   233;20180211;1;00;780..;m
   233;1111;2;5647;3434;..;n
   233;1111;2;5647;4545;..;n
   233;1111;2;5647;3453;..;n
```

The problem statement is say I need to copy second column of record matching "1;00;" to following records until the next "1;00;" match and then copy the second column of that record  further until next "1;00;" match. The match pattern "1;00;" could change as well.
It could be say "2;20;" . In that case I need to copy the second column until there is either "1;00;" or "2;20;" match.

I can do this using a while loop but I really need to do this using awk or sed as the file is huge and while may take a lot of time.

Expected output:

```
   233;20180514;1;00;456..;m
   233;20180514;1111;2;5647;6754;..;n+1
   233;20180514;1111;2;5647;2342;..;n+1
   233;20180514;1111;2;5647;p234;..;n+1
   233;20180211;1;00;780..;m
   233;20180211;1111;2;5647;3434;..;n+1
   233;20180211;1111;2;5647;4545;..;n+1
   233;20180211;1111;2;5647;3453;..;n+1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we know that 1111;2 is not a good match, you tell about 2;20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP have changed the sample Input_file in question so adding code as per the new sample now.

```
awk -F";" '
length($2)==8 && !($3=="1" && $4=="00"){
   flag=""}
($3=="1" && $4=="00"){
   val=$2;
   $2="";
   sub(/;;/,";");
   flag=1;
   print;
   next
}
flag{
   $2=val OFS $2;
   $NF=$NF"+1"
}
1
' OFS=";"  Input_file
```

Basically checking if length of 2nd field of 8 and 3rd and 4th fields are NOT `1` and `0` conditions, rather than checking `;1;0`.

---

---

If your actual Input_file is same as shown samples then following may help you.

```
awk -F";" 'NF==5 || !/pay;$/{flag=""} /1;00;$/{val=$2;$2="";sub(/;;/,";");flag=1} flag{$2=val OFS $2} 1' OFS=";"  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F";" '         ##Setting field separator as semi colon for all the lines here.
NF==5 || !/pay;$/{  ##Checking condition if number of fields are 5 on a line OR line is NOT ending with pay; if yes then do following.
  flag=""}          ##Setting variable flag value as NULL here.
/1;00;$/{           ##Searching string /1;00; at last of a line if it is found then do following:
  val=$2;           ##Creating variable named val whose value is $2(3nd field of current line).
  $2="";            ##Nullifying 2nd column now for current line.
  sub(/;;/,";");    ##Substituting 2 continous semi colons with single semi colon to remove 2nd columns NULL value.
  flag=1}           ##Setting value of variable flag as 1 here.
flag{               ##Checking condition if variable flag is having values then do following.
  $2=val OFS $2}    ##Re-creating value of $2 as val OFS $2, basically adding value of 2nd column of pay; line here.
1                   ##awk works on concept of condition then action so mentioning 1 means making condition TRUE and no action mentioned so print will happen of line.
' OFS=";" Input_file ##Setting OFS as semi colon here and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Ravinder. Your answer does solve my example. Although the file may not contain just 5 fields and pay is just an example. It could have any value as last column. I will update the example set. Could you please help me understand the logic.

Comment: @Madie, sure added explanation now. Also you could remove `NF` condition there and put like `!/pay;$/ && length($2)==8` but again it will depend on your Input_file too. Let me know how it goes then??

Comment: @Madie, ahhhhh you have changed sample Input a lot, let me fix it now my code and update my post too now.